# Group by with filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I've got the following three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SurveyComments](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[QuestionNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[Comment] [varchar](250) NULL,
[FIleName] [nchar](50) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SurveyQuestions](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[QuestionNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[Description] [varchar](250) NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SurveyResponses](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[SurveyQuestionNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[Answer1] [bit] NULL,
[Answer2] [bit] NULL,
[Answer3] [bit] NULL,
[Answer4] [bit] NULL,
[Answer5] [bit] NULL,
[Answer6] [bit] NULL,
[FileName] [nchar](50) NULL)
```

I'm expecting all questions and answers listed for those sets where a Questionnaire set (FileName) included Answer1 to Q43.

```
   SELECT SurveyQuestionNumber
    , SurveyQuestions.Description
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Answer1 = 1 THEN 1 END) 'Answer 1'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Answer2 = 1 THEN 1 END) 'Answer 2'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Answer3 = 1 THEN 1 END) 'Answer 3'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Answer4 = 1 THEN 1 END) 'Answer 4'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Answer5 = 1 THEN 1 END) 'Answer 5'
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN Answer6 = 1 THEN 1 END) 'Answer 6'
    FROM [StaffSurveyQuestionnaire_2019].[dbo].[SurveyResponses]
    JOIN SurveyQuestions on SurveyResponses.SurveyQuestionNumber = SurveyQuestions.QuestionNumber
    GROUP BY SurveyQuestionNumber, Description
    order by SurveyQuestionNumber asc
```

This gives me grouping and counts for all the answers. Sample data for this query

[image]

I tried `having count(case when QuestNumber = 53 then 1 end) > 0` but that returns only one row for question specified in the where clause but I want all questions listed with counts of answers where in all questionnaire sets where someone Answer1 = 1 to Q53 for example. So This will list all Q1 - Q60 with answer counts only for the sets where Q53 was answered as Answer1 = 1

Comment: Simplify the question. Show us both sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, no images. Take a look at [mcve] too.

Comment: Images of your object explorer doesn't tell us anything about your tables. We need Sample data as DDL and DML statements, and your expected results.

Comment: @Larnu I've simplified it and provided DDL objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your query

```
    WHERE [FileName] IN (SELECT [FileName] FROM [StaffSurveyQuestionnaire_2019].[dbo].[SurveyResponses]
                        WHERE SurveyQuestionNumber=43 and Answer1=1)
```

Comment: Yep, I figured it out myself. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I'm expecting all questions and answers listed for those sets where a
>   Questionnaire set (FileName) included Answer1 to Q43.

You probably need a `WHERE FileName IN (...)` condition which could also be written as `WHERE EXISTS (...)`:

```
FROM SurveyResponses
JOIN SurveyQuestions ON SurveyResponses.SurveyQuestionNumber = SurveyQuestions.QuestionNumber
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM SurveyResponses AS q43a1
    WHERE q43a1.QuestionNumber = 43
    AND q43a1.Answer1 = 1
    AND q43a1.FileName = SurveyResponses.FileName
)
GROUP BY SurveyQuestionNumber, Description
```

Comment: I'm expecting all questions and answers listed for those sets where a Questionnaire set (FileName) included Answer1 to Q43.